# Precision and Accuracy

Tags: floating-point

How would I go about calculating the precision and accuracy of a given number?

For example
    0.05 has an accuracy of 2 and a precision of 3.
    1 has an accuracy of 0 and a precision of 1.

Is there an algorithm for calculating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the correct (or reference) value to get the accuracy of a number, which presumably is a measurement of something.  So, in your question you've actually just *stated* the accuracy of those numbers.  I'll take your word for it.

Precision is expressed usually as the finest gradation of your measurement.  So, the precision for $0.05$ could be $0.01, 0.05,$ or even $0.025 = 1/40$.  Again, it depends on how you're measuring.